# Where is the "sites/all" folder for an ubuntu linux installation?

Tags: 7

I have installed drupal 7 from the ubuntu repositories.  All works well but I cannot locate the folder to install additional modules.

All the documentation says I need to upload files to the "sites/all" folder. This either doesn't exist or is somewhere I have yet to look.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

ETA: I had to create the "/all/modules/contrib" subfolders manually, under the "/usr/share/drupal7/sites" absolute path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's referring to the "sites/all" folder in your website's root folder.

The location of your site's files will have been set by your web server software (probably Apache, in this case).

Have a look here:  /var/www/

and see if there are any directories in there that look like "httpdocs" or anything with your site's name in it or anything.

Comment: I'm afraid not. There is a "html" folder in "/var/www" but it has nothing drupal related. Apache is serving some other static files from there, however.

Comment: In my ":/usr/share/drupal7/sites/" folder I only have "default"

Comment: it must be serving from there then.  I've never installed it like that,  but you should just be able to create a directory (readable by your web service!). create a /usr/share/drupal7/sites/all/modules/  and put your modules in there and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

As user5482 said, all your Drupal files are probably in this folder `/usr/share/drupal7/sites/`

Just to make sure, you could run this command (if locate command is available in your distribution) and see what paths you get:

```
updatedb
locate "sites/default"
```

If by default the `sites/all` folder is not created, you need to create it yourself.
You could run:

```
mkdir /usr/share/drupal7/sites/all
```

Make sure it has the same permissions and owner as the `sites/default` folder:
Check what are the permissions:

```
ls -lh /usr/share/drupal7/sites/ | grep default
```

In my case I have something like this:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data 4.0K Mar  3 16:35 default
```

So to replicate it run (adjust it with your own permissions):

```
chown www-data:www-data /usr/share/drupal7/sites/all
chmod 775 /usr/share/drupal7/sites/all
```